# no error message, nothing, but it does not work (512byte boot file)

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, x86-16, bootloader

Yeah, basically I want to change from a 16-bit system to a 32, (later 64 when it will work) but it does not work. Nasm didn't give me an error, but it doesin't run in virtualbox. Here is a link if someone understands assembly:

https://github.com/Xulum12/assembly/blob/main/boot2.asm

```
[org 0x7c00] 

GDT_Start:
null_descriptor:
dd 0
dd 0
code_descriptor:
dw 0xffff
dw 0
dw 0
db 10011010

db 11001111

db 0

data_descriptor:
dw 0xffff
dw 0
dw 0
db 10010010

db 11001111

db 0
GDT_end:

GDT_Descriptor:
dw GDT_end - GDT_Start - 1
dd GDT_Start

CODE_SEG equ code_descriptor - GDT_Start
DATA_SEG equ data_descriptor - GDT_Start

cli
lgdt [GDT_Descriptor]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax

jmp CODE_SEG:stpm
[bits 32]
stpm:

mov al, 'q'
mov ah, 0x0f
mov [0xb8000], ax

times 510-($-$$) db 0              
db 0x55, 0xaa
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show how you're building and running the image this creates.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step.  Your best bet is to run it inside Bochs with its built-in debugger, as it knows about segmentation and modes, and can help you debug the transition to protected mode.

Answer (score 4):

Some reasons why it fails include:

- The data gets executed as if it was code
- The descriptors have 9 bytes instead of 8
- The segment registers have not been setup
- There's no decent end for the code
- ...

Answer (score 3):

Your code starts with data. CPU treats data as instructions which can do unexpected things. You need to either move data to end of the code, or add a `JMP` instruction at the beginning of the code that skips the data bytes.

Comment: If I jmp to GDT_end then the Virtualbox just says that there was a critic error. @Sedat

Comment: @Xulum12 Because there's still data after GDT_End. You need to jump directly at `cli` instruction.

Comment: I tried it, It outputs the same meditation error thingy.

Comment: @Xulum12 That means you have a different problem now. You might need to initialize `DS` selector correctly, as `mov [0xb8000], ax` defaults to it.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: @Xulum12 `mov ax, DATA_SEG` + `mov ds, ax` for example?

Comment: I get the same error. If its important I convert it by Dosbox with nasm and the command is NASM boot.asm -o boot.img

Comment: Then, it's time for you to set up a debugger using QEMU and see what's going wrong. I'm not sure if Dosbox has good enough debugging facilities for that. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Debugging_with_QEMU

Comment: Qemu doesn't work on my computer. Even if i choose windows.

Comment: @Xulum12 apparently, DosBox-X has a debugger too: https://github.com/joncampbell123/dosbox-x/blob/master/README.debugger

Comment: I finally got it working, copied a 64bit code too, but NASM gave me this error: boot.asm: 167 error: 64 is not a valid segment size, must be 16 or 32, boot.asm:178 warning: numeric constant 0x1F201F201F201F20 does not fit in 32 bits. know that the 32 bit part is working, the 64 probably not, but I should be able to compile it, because i searched it and NASM can compile 64 bit assembly too, so i don't know what is th problem. the code is: https://github.com/Xulum12/assembly/blob/main/boot64bits

Comment: @Xulum12 congrats! it's actually a great achievement to switch to protected mode and do anything without crashing. anything will feel easier after this.

Comment: I did it, it can compile it, I just need to do this basically all over again to boot into 64 bits.